# Update DB field on checkbox change - AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

How can I update one field in MySQL table after user clicks on checkbox.
I have this:

```
<div style="float: right"><input type="checkbox" class="tvSync" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" onclick="myFunction({{$spot->spotid}})"></div>
```

and

```
function myFunction(id)
  {   
  var  spotid=spotid;  
    $.ajax({
      type:'post',
      url:'updateTvSync',
      data:{spotid: spotid},
      success:function(msg){
        console.log(msg)
 }
 });

}
```

I created the route `/updateSync` and included it in controller:

```
public function updateTvSync(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->spotid;

        TV::where('spotid', $id)->update(['delayed' => 1]);
    }
```

but when I click on checkbox nothing happens. Does this `<div>` need to be in form or am I missing something here?

Comment: have you checked what is in your actual html? as in inspect element and see if it actually inserted the `$spot->spotid`

Comment: Yes. I have `onclick="myFunction(469871)"` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to give id to your checkbox and remove onclick function

```
<input id="{{$spot->spotid}}" type="checkbox" class="tvSync" data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success">
```

Add this JQuery , you are calling wrong route `/updateTvSync` instead of `/updateSync` . in your ajax url.

```
<script>
$(document).on('click','.tvSync',function(){
  var id=$(this).attr('id');
  alert(id);

      $.ajax({
         type:'post',
         url:'/updateSync',
         data:{spotid: id},
         success:function(msg){
           console.log(msg)
         }
      });

 });
</script>
```

Comment: why would onclick be wrong? Ididn't see the url mistake :-)

Comment: I would not put the spotid in the id attr: there can be only one of the same id on a page! using data-spotid would be better

Comment: `data-toggle="toggle"`is preventing the ajax call. Any solutions?

Comment: just remove that

Comment: But I need it :D... I don't want to have simple checkbox but the one from bootstraptoggle.

Answer (score 4):

```
 var  spotid=spotid;
```

should be

```
 var  spotid=id;
```

spotid is undefined

Comment: I fixed it but still nothing happens. Also I get nothing in console.

Comment: or data:{spotid: id}, and remove the extra var

Comment: try to console.log the id

Comment: If you put a  console.log(id); as first line of the function, it should give a error or log in the console, either the function is not defined or the console.log shows

Comment: That's why it is weird to me because nothing happens. Btw I use this http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ for the checkbox.. Could it be the problem?

Comment: The onclick could be prevented by other js code, so yes it could be the problem

Comment: You can check if that is the problem by trying `onclick="alert('onclick works');"`

Comment: Yeah. It's because of the bootstraptoggle... Is it possible to solve this? I don't want simple checkbox :(

Comment: try using SaurabhMistrys approach with a clicklistener instead of an onclick attribute

Comment: onchange i think, not sure

Comment: @Cashbee the clicklistner will not work because you are not clicking the actual checkbox when using bootstraptoggle.

Comment: oh yeah that makes sense. Maybe make a listener like in SaurabhMistrys answer but instead of listening to 'click', listen to 'change' ?

Comment: Not working... When I insert `data-toggle="toggle"` nothing happens.